# PointToScreen returning variable results during layout

Tags: c#, winforms

**EDIT:**

So far all the answers have pointed out the code as originally written was hacky.  I didn't write it, and don't understand fully how it all worked.  **However**, in the general case, it did work.  I have tried various tidy-ups, but they don't fix the basic problem, because of the strange behaviour of `PointToScreen`.

An alternative to explaining that behaviour, which I can see is difficult to explain without understanding the inner working of the rest of the form (and I don't at the moment), is to come up with an alternative way to implement the desired functionality, which is a small dialog appearing on top of a button when the button is pressed.  The current implementation is a form which appears on top, and then tracks the original form to maintain its position.  Is there a cleaner option?

**Original Question:**

I'm trying to position a form (form A) on top of a control (button B) on a form (form C) using `PointToScreen`:

```
Point buttonCorner = buttonB.Parent.PointToScreen(buttonB.Location);
```

where `buttonB` is a button in a `FlowLayoutPanel` on a form.

Most of the time it works, I get the position I expect.  I use this code in a `LocationChanged` event on the form, so that form A tracks button B.  This is working fine.

However, when another action causes the parent form to be resized, I find that the position of `buttonCorner` is offset, such that form A ends up off the screen (to the right).  No part of my form is off the screen before this event.

The only theory I can come up with is that the `LocationChanged` event is firing while the  `FlowLayoutPanel` is re-arranging, and it returns a bad position during that time.  It seems a little far-fetched, but I don't have a better theory.

Comment: I guess the `LocationChanged` is of your form?

Comment: @KingKing yes, it's of the form

Comment: See my answer, you should not use `LocationChanged` of your form, you should also make it clearer on your controls layout and your purpose.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose you have `panelA` and `panelB`. You have to register the `LocationChanged` of the `panelB` not of the form:

```
panelB.LocationChanged += (s,e) => {
  Point buttonCorner = PanelControlFlow.PointToScreen(PanelControlFlow.Location);
  //...
};
```

Anyway I can feel that your code has wrong approach, your 2 controls may not need to track each other unless you change their locations at runtime. You should provide more details so that we can find another better approach. Note that the `FlowLayoutPanel` will compact the controls automatically and positioning controls on it won't have any effect.

**UPDATE**:
For the reason why your `PointToScreen` returns some off-screen Point. I've tested this, when the form is minimized, its `Location` is `-32000, -32000`. All the `PointToScreen` will be added with this `Location`, that means if your control has `Left` calculated on your form is `300`, then its `Left` calculated on the screen will be approximately `-32000 + 300 = -31700`. The same for `Top`. That's why your control's Location goes off screen. So you have to register the `LocationChanged` of the control you want to track to not the form. Why does the minimized window have `Location` of `-32000,-32000`? I think that's how a Window is hidden from screen.

Comment: In general, I agree with you.  The code has grown organically and is not very clean.  However I would like to understand specifically why `PointToScreen` returns values off the screen. Without understanding that, I'm reluctant to make major changes to a large and complex form.

Comment: I realised the original question was a bit confusing.  The tracking item is actually a form, not a control.  I've updated the question to clarify.

Comment: It's interesting to know that PointToScreen returns very negative values when minimized, but that's not the problem I'm seeing.  None of my UI is minimized, and I see values offset by about 300 pixels.  It's close enough that I think the position is __related__ to the control being tracked, but not in the way I expect.

Answer (score 1):

```
 Point buttonCorner = PanelControlFlow.PointToScreen(PanelControlFlow.Location);
```

That code is definitely wrong, the Location value is relative to the control's Parent.  If you want to know where the panel's upper-left corner is located then you must use:

```
 Point panelCorner = PanelControlFlow.PointToScreen(Point.Empty);
```

or for a button in the panel:

```
 Point buttonCorner = someButtonInPanel.Parent.PointToScreen(someButtonInPanel.Location);
```

Then to get another button on top:

```
 anotherButton.Location = anotherButton.Parent.PointToClient(buttonCorner);
```

Comment: I agree with your comments, and have updated my code and question to match.  However it doesn't fix the original problem...PointToScreen is still returning offset values during the resize operation of the master form.

Comment: All I really know is that the original code was fundamentally broken, no idea how you could *possibly* ever have gotten that button to overlap.  Lord knows what you hacked in the other code that positions the form to fix that.  Whatever is still going wrong is impossible to guess at, that's code I cannot see.

Comment: It's a fair comment that it was broken, I spent some time trying to understand how it was meant to work myself.  Actually `PanelControlFlow.Location` was always returning `(0,0)`, so it operated in the same way as your first suggestion.  I have updated my original question to try to move away from overly specific focus on `PointToScreen` and move towards a solution to the underlying problem.